# after Mysql UNION SELECT $stmt .. i got data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

After Mysql UNION SELECT $stmt. I got data from multiple tables now the task is to select id from actual table

I used to get data is

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM city UNION SELECT * FROM fruit ORDER BY CreatedTime ASC LIMIT 15');

$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
```

echo $id ; 
echo $userName ;

I got data like 
1 - hyderavbads
2 - banana
3 - orange
4 - delhi

Now  I need to select actual id and get the value from original table

Comment: Can you add the table structure for both of the tables and also put some data and expected output.

Comment: table city contain
1 - Hyderabad
2 - Chennai
3 - Bangalore
4 - Surat
5 - Delhi
6 - Rajkot
7 - Ahmedabad
8 - Goa

table friuts contacci
1 - banana
2 - orange
3 - staberry
4 - graphs
5 - pomogranet
6 - guvva


now i got data like

1 - Hyderabad
2 - graphs
3 - surat
4 - guvva
5 - orange
6 - delhi

now i need to get actual id from orginal table

Comment: One more doubt, for example in city table record "1 - Hyderabad" does this contain in the single column or something like ID contains "1" and city_name contains "Hyderabad". If this is the case then you can refer answer posted by "Jeffry Evan" that will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: ID contains "1" and city_name contains "Hyderabad".

Comment: I have posted the complete logic for implementation, lets try it once and let us know if there is any issue.

Answer (score 0):

there's no way you can know the original table from that union result using your current query.

you might want to change the query to something like this so you know where the original table for that ID

```
SELECT id,value,'city' as tblName FROM city UNION SELECT id,value,'fruit' as tblName FROM fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, here is the logic how to implement, check out and let us know if there is any issue.

```
mysql> create table city(id int, city_name varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)

mysql> create table fruits(id int, fruit_name varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.40 sec)

mysql> insert into city values(1,'Hyderabad');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into fruits values(1,'Banana');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> SELECT id,city_name,'city' source FROM city UNION  SELECT id,fruit_name,'fruits' FROM fruits;
+------+-----------+--------+
| id   | city_name | source |
+------+-----------+--------+
|    1 | Hyderabad | city   |
|    1 | Banana    | fruits |
+------+-----------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)


$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT id,city_name FROM city UNION SELECT id,fruit_name FROM fruit ORDER BY CreatedTime ASC LIMIT 15');

$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);

    ---write here a case/if statement like
    If($source=="city")
    {
        --again prepare the statement and select the data from city table like
        $stmt_city = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT id,city_name,other_col_val FROM city where id = $id');
    }
    else
    {
        --again prepare the statement and select the data from fruits table like
        $stmt_city = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT id,fruit_name,other_col_val FROM fruits where id = $id');
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i got all the data from 2 different tables in ul list now what i need is i need to <a href = echo id > for that particular item to the id which is in orginal table id with other page like tableoneview.php?id=123 and table2view.php?id=123 please help me on this

Comment: I am not much familiar with PHP, that's why I gave the idea for implementation.